# how to Add a database on the server to be accessible by all computers on the server

Tags: sqlplus

I made a sample database for my students to learn SQL
in that i created it and saved it
i added 30 entries to it
and i saved it
and i cannot copy the same file to 100 computers in my lab
so tell me how to do this

i searched the net but to no avail

```
sql> tables

----------------------------------- 
dhana
-----------------------------------
task completed in 0.57 seconds
```

i want to put the same database in 100 computers but i cannot do it it will take long time to open the windows xp computer and copy the file from the network paste it and shut down the computer is too tedious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm. 
refer the computer science for class 11 with python by Sumita Arora
and u may get it.
u are not searching the net properly
and the questions are kind of easy to be found on google
what is ur webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like mysql workbench and access your server remotely, although I've never tried 100 simultaneous connections. Another option is ssh from clients into your server and use database cli. Of course i assume you want *one* database and many clients. Not many databases.